Upload flutter macOS app to TestFlight with fastlane
I want to use Github Actions to upload a macOS app to TestFlight. For iOS I do the following:
flutter build ipa --export-options-plist=${{ github.workspace }}/ios/exportOptions.plist

Then with fastlane:
desc "Upload to TestFlight"
lane :distribute do
  upload_to_testflight(
    api_key: api_key,
    ipa: "../path/to/ipa",
    skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true
  )
end

My problem is that flutter build macos doesn't generate an .ipa or a .pkg but an .app. What am I supposed to do to upload the macOS app to TestFlight?

The first thing you need to do is create and download a Mac Installer Distribution certificate here: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/add
Then you need to use productbuild to create a .pkg file using the .app file generated by flutter build macos:
productbuild \
    --sign "Mac Installer Distribution certificate" \
    --component path/to/App.app /Applications path/to/App.pkg

NOTE: The [install-path] parameter of productbuild must be /Applications. Otherwise you'll get an asset validation error when trying to upload to TestFlight.
Then you can upload the .pkg file using upload_to_testflight:
desc "Upload to TestFlight"
lane :distribute do
  upload_to_testflight(
    api_key: "api_key",
    pkg: "path/to/App.pkg"
  )
end

